# How is it possible that "RemoveAll" in LINQ is much faster than iteration?

Tags: c#, performance, linq

The following code:

```
List<Interval> intervals = new List<Interval>();
List<int> points = new List<int>();

//Initialization of the two lists
// [...]

foreach (var point in points)
{
    intervals.RemoveAll (x => x.Intersects (point));
}
```

is at least 100x faster than this when the lists are of size ~10000:

```
List<Interval> intervals = new List<Interval>();
List<int> points = new List<int>();

//Initialization of the two lists
// [...]

foreach (var point in points)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < intervals.Count;)
    {
        if (intervals[i].Intersects(point))
        {
            intervals.Remove(intervals[i]);
        }
        else
        {
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

How is it possible? What is performed under the hood with "RemoveAll"? According to [MSDN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Developer_Network), "RemoveAll" performs a linear search and is therefore in O(n). So I would expect similar performance for both.

When replacing "Remove" by "RemoveAt", the iteration is much faster, comparable to "RemoveAll". But *both* "Remove" and "RemoveAt" have O(n) complexity, so why is the performance difference between them so big? Could it only be due to the fact that "Remove (item)" compares the list elements with "item" and "RemoveAt" doesn't perform any comparison?

Comment: `RemoveAll` does not use LINQ, it is a standard method on `List<T>`. This is noted by the fact that `RemoveAll` modifies the collection *in place* - LINQ does not modify collections.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! I posted too fast...

Comment: @Brainless, you can speed up 2nd code sample, if use `intervals.RemoveAt(i);`  instead of `intervals.Remove (intervals[i]);`, I think.

Comment: FWIW, a better approach might be to actually use LINQ and use `.Except` on the List and operate on the returned enumerable. This ensures you don't modify the original list and won't perform any processing until you actually enumerate the results.

Comment: I replaced "Remove" by "RemoveAt" and the 2 speeds are now comparable. However "RemoveAll" is still sensibly faster.

Comment: Both `RemoveAll` and `Remove` are `O(n)`, so it's easy to believe the one which has an additional `for` loop will perform `n` times slower.

Comment: Here's the LINQ way: `intervals.Where(i => !points.Any(p => i.Intersects(p))).ToList();`. Not more efficient but possibly more readable.

Comment: @Brainless RemoveAt doesn't perform any comparison, it simply removes the item at the specified position. Remove on the other hand has to *search* for the item that is equal to its argument.

Comment: @TimSchmelter +1 It's always good to have generics manipulations in LINQ, but I'm not sure if it's more readable... We could argue over readability here

Comment: @DanPantry Actually I want to modify the original list

Comment: @Brainless: imo the best approach(in terms of readability and performance) is a combination of `RemoveAll` and LINQ: `intervals.RemoveAll(i => points.Any(p => i.Intersects(p)));`

Answer (score 35, accepted):

If you remove an item from a `List<T>`, all the items after it will be moved back one spot. So if you remove n items, a lot of items will be moved n times.
RemoveAll will only do the moving once, which you can see in the source for `List<T>`: [source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,82567b42bbfc416e,references)

Another thing is that `Remove(T item)` will search the entire List for the item, so that's another n operations.

Something that has nothing to do with your question, but I'd like to point out anyway:
If you use a for-loop to delete items from a List, it's a lot easier to start at the end:

```
for (int i = intervals.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    if (intervals[i].Intersects(point))
    {
        intervals.RemoveAt(i);
    }
}
```

This way, you don't need that ugly else-clause

Comment: Why decreasing iteration?

Comment: @Brainless because if starting from the end, you don't have to "compensate" your `i` when removing, and get rid of the `else` clause, which makes for more readable code. By the way, your original loop is wrong... it'll move 2 slots forward when not removing (not one): the `for` statement will increase one, and your `else` will increase another

Comment: @Brainless. If you remove let's say list[3], all the items at index 4, 5, etc will be moved back one spot. But that's territory were you've already been. It won't mess with items 0,1 and 2.

Comment: @Brainless Because if you remove items, you don’t end up skipping the next element (since the index should stay the same instead). As you can see, when iterating backwards, you don’t need to do the `i++/i--` separately within the loop body.

Comment: @Brainless because moving from bottom to top does not require skipping increase in counter for one spot if an item is removed..

Comment: @Jcl No, OP’s loop was correct but an edit incorrectly added a `i++` to the for construct.

Comment: @poke I see that, sorry, missed the revision history :-)

Comment: If you check the revision history, people have continuously added and removed and added and removed etc... the "++i" in the for loop...

Comment: It also has the potential to be significantly faster.  Consider the extreme case where all elements are removed from the list: if you start from the back, there's no "shifting" of the remaining elements, so it's O(n).  If you start from the front, it's O(n²) because each removal requires shifting the remainder of the list

Comment: @MarkSowul Indeed. If you go forward, you're shifting items you're going to delete later anyway. It's just unnecessary work.

Answer (score 12):

`RemoveAll` can be done in `O(n)` by checking the condition for `n` elements and moving at most `n` elements.

Your loop is `O(n^2)`, as each `Remove` needs to check up to `n` elements. And even if you change it to `RemoveAt`, it still needs to move up to `n` elements.

This might be the fastest solution:
`intervals.RemoveAll(x => points.Any(x.Intersects));`

Answer (score 3):

`List` is an array, and removing one element from an array requires moving all elements after the one you're removing to the previous index, so `a[i]` is moved to `a[i-1]`.

Doing this repeatedly requires multiple moves, even if more elements meet the removal criteria. `RemoveAll` may optimize this by moving the elements by more than 1 index at a time as it traverses the list and finds more elements that match the removal criteria.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that Remove itself is an O(n), so you get O(n^2).

Replace `for` with a new collection and an assignment.

```
items = items.Where(i => ...).ToList();
```

This method has the same algorithmic time complexity as RemoveAll, but uses extra O(n) memory.

Comment: I doubt RemoveAll would do that; that uses O(n) extra memory.

Comment: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,82567b42bbfc416e

Comment: Updated the answer to be more precise on that part.